# What motiveted Gauss to formulate his theorem on quadratic reprocity?

Tags: number-theory

Im trying to connect his work on quadratic reciprocity with some simple question, like solution to certain diophantine equation or representing primes. Any ideas? I find it hard to imagine that he out of the blue just wanted to characterize the primes for which certain equations were solvable. I did read something about him wanting to write primes as sums of squares just like Fermat had done  in $p=x^{2}+y^{2}$ for instance. But having $ax^{2}+bx+c=pk$ dont look like an attempt to achieve this, he doesn't seam to try getting $k=1$ either

Comment: Are you trying to learn this directly from the *Disquisitiones*?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, I looked into some of Fermat's work aswell.

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity was discovered by Euler (without proof)

Comment: @user8268 any idea what his question was?

Comment: sorry, very unreliable info: Euler was trying to prove Fermat's claims about primes of the from $x^2+ny^2$; he did it for $n=1$, maybe for some other $n$'s (?). If $\mathbb Z(\sqrt{-n})$ is a UFD then knowing that $-n$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ is enough to conclude that $p=x^2+ny^2$. Anyway, Euler's form of reciprocity is (as I read) different from Gauss's, namely: $(d/p)$ depends only on $p$ mod $4d$.

Comment: @GrigoryM Can you write this in an answer then ill close the question with that. Lemmemyer provides alot of nice info regarding my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Chapter 1 of *Cox. Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* and Chapter 1 of *Lemmermeyer. Reciprocity Laws: From Euler to Eisenstein* for some info and further references.